# plotly - y axis values aren't sorted properly

Tags: javascript, plotly

i am using node js and socket.io to gather some values from arduino and then visualize them on a webpage, the 'gathering' part should be fine. But when i look at the plot provided by Arduino IDE, i see something a bit different that my plotly is doing.
The weird thing is that the y axis values aren't sorted out as the graph goes on and i have no idea on why is that happening, can anyone please help? [This is the wrong plot,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO4zX.png)[this is the right one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOwhW.png). And my code here:

```
<div id="ivValue"></div>
<div id="ivPlot"></div>

<script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('ivValue').innerHTML = data; 
        });

    Plotly.plot('ivPlot',[{
        y:[document.getElementById('ivValue').innerHTML],
        type:'line'
    }]);

    setInterval(function() {
        Plotly.extendTraces('ivPlot', { y: [[document.getElementById('ivValue').innerHTML]] }, [0])
    }, 6);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone discovers this in future and has the same problem, i have discovered what was the problem here.
ivValue was provided by socket.io library, basically it's output from it communicating with (i think) and there's probably something wrong with the data type these values were drawn into html page or taken out of it by script.
The easiest workaround is to simply do this to the algorithm that draws these values into a plot:

```
document.getElementById('ivValue').innerHTML*1
```